# How to list categories within tags?

Tags: categories, tags

I'm currently working on an ecommerce site with WooCommerce. I'm using product categories for product types (e.g. cards, DVD's), and product tags for topics/themes (e.g. Christmas, children).

What I'd like is for product types/categories to be displayed within topics/tags, so that I could navigate from "Christmas" > "DVD's", for example, and find all the DVD's relating to Christmas. How would I go about doing this?